# Sql syntax for alias

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select DB.lname as "Friend Last Name"
from DB
```

In my browser it is displayed as: "Friend_Last_Name".

Why has it replaced spaces with underscores? In sql 2012 it appears as "Friend Last Name" as it is meant to.

Comment: I've tried to rephrase your question for you, please feel free to change if I've got the wrong end of the stick. Also - could you please change the tags to be more specific unless you need a solution that works on multiple RDBMS.

Comment: How are you viewing the results "In browser"?

Comment: Please clarify. Which SQL server is involved with this problem? MySQL? sqlite? What SQL client are you using?

Comment: this cant be for all those different sql versions please identify which SQL database you are using. MySQL <> SQL server and SQLite is something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select DB.lname [Friend Last Name]
from DB
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for unclear question wording!

Comment: you welcome! be aware, that the resultset of the query is processed by "web software" and then displayed as words/numbers in Your browser. A lot of data conversion/rearrangement can take place in these steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DB.lname as [Friend Last Name]
from DB
```